# How to make one query to my code

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

How to make one query to my code

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM countries WHERE country_code = LEFT($number,3)"; 
$sql = "SELECT id FROM countries WHERE country_code = LEFT($number,2)"; 
$sql = "SELECT id FROM countries WHERE country_code = LEFT($number,1)"; 
$sql = "SELECT id FROM countries WHERE country_code = 0";
```

Comment: Use this query `$sql = "SELECT id FROM countries WHERE country_code IN  (LEFT($number,3), LEFT($number,2), LEFT($number,1) ,0 )"`

Comment: $sql = select id from countries where country_code in (LEFT($number,3), LEFT($number,2), LEFT($number,1), 0);

Comment: @Gaurav it would work like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT id
FROM countries
WHERE country_code = LEFT($number,3)
  OR country_code = LEFT($number,2)
  OR country_code = LEFT($number,1)
  OR country_code = 0";
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon you condition if you want strict then use AND if not then OR

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM countries WHERE country_code = LEFT($number,3) OR 
        country_code = LEFT($number,2) OR country_code = LEFT($number,1) OR 
        country_code =0 ";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    // if you want want result from table for all condition true than write 
   //below query
    $sql= "SELECT id 
           FROM countries 
           WHERE country_code = LEFT($number,3)
           AND country_code = LEFT($number,2)
           AND country_code = LEFT($number,1)
           AND country_code = LEFT($number,0)" 

    // if you want result for OR condition

    $sql= "SELECT id 
           FROM countries 
           WHERE country_code = LEFT($number,3)
           OR country_code = LEFT($number,2)
           OR country_code = LEFT($number,1)
           OR country_code = LEFT($number,0)"
```